# function to list earthquakes

Tags: python, list, function

my function is designed to take the data from this website and collect the latitude, longitude, depth, and magnitude of the earthquake. The second function 'colorCode' is supposed to take the depth of the earthquake and return a color value with it. this is where I am stuck. I tried to make the data a float so I could use a if statement and compare it to an int but it still says it cannot be converted to float. any thoughts? (excuse me if I post the code in an improper format)

```
import urllib

#parseEarthquake: int --> list-of-float

def parseEarthquakeData(numberofearthquakes):
    URLonWeb = urllib.urlopen("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.csv")
    lines = URLonWeb.readlines()
    numberoflines = len(lines)
    numberoftimes = 0
    index = 1
    myaccumalator = []
    for numberoftimes in range(numberofearthquakes):
        while index < (numberofearthquakes + 1):
            line = lines[index]
            data = line.split(",")
            latitude = float(data[1])
            longitude = float(data[2])
            depth = float(data[3])
            magnitude = float(data[4])
            if magnitude < 2.5:
                magnitude = 2.5
            myList = [[latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude]]
            myaccumalator = myaccumalator + myList
            index = index + 1
        return(myaccumalator)


#return [latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude]

def colorCode(numberofQuakes):
    data = parseEarthquakeData(2)
    data =str(data)
    realdata = data.split()
    if realdata[2] <34:
        print 'orange'
        if realdata[2] >=34<70:
            print 'yellow'
            if realdata[2] >=70<150:
                print 'green'
                if realdata[2] >=150<300:
                    print 'blue'
                    if realdata[2] >=300<500:
                        print 'purple'
                        if realdata[2] >=500:
                            print 'red'
```

Comment: I don't think you want to have all those `if` statements indented like that.

Comment: What precise error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a very convenient `csv.DictReader` module for what you are trying to achieve. I changed your code around a bit to make it shorter and more readbale:

```
import urllib
import csv

#parseEarthquake: int --> list-of-float

def parseEarthquakeData(numberofearthquakes):
    URLonWeb = urllib.urlopen("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.csv")
    lines = URLonWeb.readlines()
    content = csv.DictReader(lines)
    allEarthquakes = [line for line in content]
    return allEarthquakes[:numberofearthquakes]


#return [latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude]

def colorCode(numberofQuakes):
    data = parseEarthquakeData(2)
    for earthquake in data:
        depth = float(earthquake["depth"])
        print(depth)
        if depth <34:
            print 'orange'
        elif 34 <= depth <70:
            print 'yellow'
        if 70 <= depth <150:
            print 'green'
```

The `dictReader` converts every line into a dictionary with the corresponding headers from the csv file. Doing this is good because your structured data is much more readible in a dictionary compared to a list (you don't have to remember which position is what).

You also had some problems with the number comparison in you color code method, compare yours to what I changed it to. Also I cannot tell what you wanted to achieve with `data =str(data)`

I did not implement the whole color logic but you should be able to adapt it to your needs.